# I cannot log in after installing MODX Revolution

Tags: php, content-management-system, modx, modx-revolution

After installing MODX Revolution I cannot log in - just a blank page is displayed. My setup: MODX downloaded from git, PHP 5.3, Apache 2.2, OS ubuntu.

In apache error log I see this message:

> [Sun Sep 04 08:03:12 2011] [error] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member 
>   function render() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/modx/manager/controllers/default/welcome.class.php on line 
>   64 [Sun Sep 04 08:03:12 2011] [error] PHP Stack trace: [Sun Sep 04
>   08:03:12 2011] [error] PHP   1. {main}()
>   /var/www/modx/manager/index.php:0 [Sun Sep 04 08:03:12 2011] [error]
>   PHP   2. modManagerRequest->handleRequest()
>   /var/www/modx/manager/index.php:71 [Sun Sep 04 08:03:12 2011] [error] 
>   PHP   3. modManagerRequest->prepareResponse()
>   /var/www/modx/core/model/modx/modmanagerrequest.class.php:124 [Sun
>   Sep 04 08:03:12 2011] [error] PHP   4.
>   modManagerResponse->outputContent()
>   /var/www/modx/core/model/modx/modmanagerrequest.class.php:173 [Sun
>   Sep 04 08:03:12 2011] [error] PHP   5. modManagerController->render() 
>   /var/www/modx/core/model/modx/modmanagerresponse.class.php:106 [Sun 
>   Sep 04 08:03:12 2011] [error] PHP   6.
>   WelcomeManagerController->process()
>   /var/www/modx/core/model/modx/modmanagercontroller.class.php:133

Comment: Did you run the transport.core.php before installation? Also did you make sure the directories "/core/packages", "/core/cache", "/core/import", and "/core/export" are writable. Make sure your php.ini setting sets memory_limit to 128M, and max_execution_time to 120 and finally did you create a blank file "/core/config/config.inc.php" and make it writable?

Comment: all this folders is writable but i not run transport.core.php. i don't get them after clone from git i just copy them ziped version. problem in this ? and i don't find in manual before install i must run transport.core.php ?

Comment: I've only installed revo 3 times but I've never had to run transport.core.php. @paulGraffix do you have a link to some documentation regarding this?

Comment: Disregard running transport.core. It was something I saw in the forums but now I realize it was something you had to do a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Paul Graffam is right in the comments, **when building from git** (either through a clone or download from github), you need to run transport.core.php as well as some other things the first time you do it.

Specific instructions can be found here: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Git+Installation

An alternative if you don't want to go through those steps is to download a nightly build from http://modx.com/download/nightlies/ - you can install them as normal there.

(Realise I'm a bit late to the question, but figured others might stuble across it in the future and there's no answer yet)